# Reading the trailing fraction part in a nanl

Tags: c, floating-point, nan, endianness

I am upgrading a working multi-platform math library (compliant with c99 standard) and have to code the `long double` extension to a couple functions (alike `sinl` for `sin`).

In particular, I have to deal with some functions that can fail in multiple ways and, in the library currently working,  I leveraged the `nan(const char *tagp)` function like this:

```
double nan_with_err(uint8_t err)
{   char buffer[4];
    snprintf(buffer, 4, "%d", err);
    return nan(buffer);
}   /*  end of nan_with_err  */

inline uint8_t geterr_from_nan(double d)
{   return *(uint64_t*)&d & 0xff;
}   /*  end of geterr_from_nan  */
```

The two functions rely on the fact that `double` and `uint64_t` have the same number of bytes and, regardless of the endianness, the less significant byte contains the trailing fraction part (no need to use more than 8 bits: actually the reasons to get a `nan` are less than a dozen).  In fact, the code can rely also on IEEE 754 which, I am told, guarantees that integers and floating-points numbers have the same endianness on the same machine.

A straightforward extension is substituting `nan` with `nanl` and writing a new function like:

```
long double nanl_with_err(uint8_t err)
{   char buffer[4];
    snprintf(buffer, 4, "%d", err);
    return nanl(buffer);
}   /*  end of nanl_with_err  */
```

Troubles arise when I am trying to retrieve the error code embedded into the `long double`, as the endianness and the number of bytes in a `long double` can vary on different machines, and there is no integer guaranteed to have the same amount of bytes than the `long double` on a given machine.

This is a working function to retrieve the error code:

```
uint8_t geterr_from_nanl(long double d)
{   uint16_t maybe_head = *(uint16_t*)&d,
             maybe_tail = *((uint16_t*)&d + sizeof(long double)/2);

    return maybe_head == 0x7fff
         ? maybe_tail & 0xFF : maybe_head & 0xFF;
}   /*  end of geterr_from_nanl  */
```

The function relies on the fact that the exponent field of `long double` is a 16-bit field (or larger?) filled with `1`, and on the assumption that integer and floating-point values have the same byte ordering.

I tested the code on a little-endian machine and on a mock-up big-endian one, and it works, but I am concerned with portability and wondering if there was a more standardized way to extract the error code from a `nanl`.

For testing, the following code is working, which incidentally also shows that the trailing fraction on `nanl` is not written onto a `nan` (of course I could shift it 2 bytes upward in the `nanl`, but it seems like asking for even more troubles).  This is the reason why I didn't wrote something like

```
inline uint8_t geterr_from_nanl(long double d) { return geterr_from_nan((double)d); }
```

Working code (compiled with `-std=c99`):

```
#include <stdio.h>   // for *printf
#include <stdint.h>  // for uint*_t
#include <math.h>    // for nan*

double nan_with_err(uint8_t err)
{   char buffer[4];
    snprintf(buffer, 4, "%d", err);
    return nan(buffer);
}   /*  end of nan_with_err  */

uint8_t geterr_from_nan(double d)
{   return *(uint64_t*)&d & 0xff;
}   /*  end of geterr_from_nan  */

long double nanl_with_err(uint8_t err)
{   char buffer[4];
    snprintf(buffer, 4, "%d", err);
    return nanl(buffer);
}   /*  end of nanl_with_err  */

uint8_t geterr_from_nanl(long double d)
{   uint16_t maybe_head = *(uint16_t*)&d,
             maybe_tail = *((uint16_t*)&d + sizeof(long double)/2);

    return maybe_head == 0x7fff
        ? maybe_tail & 0xFF : maybe_head & 0xFF;
}   /*  end of geterr_from_nanl  */

int main(void)
{   uint8_t err = 0xdb;
    double d = nan_with_err(err);
    printf("err = 0x%02X, nan  = %f, err from nan  = 0x%02X\n",
           err, d, geterr_from_nan(d));

    long double ld = nanl_with_err(err);
    printf("err = 0x%02X, nanl = %Lf, err from nanl = 0x%02X\n"
           "err from (double)nanl = 0x%02X\n",
           err, ld, geterr_from_nanl(ld), geterr_from_nan((double)ld));

    return 0;
}   /*  end of main  */
```

The code output is:

```
err = 0xDB, nan  = nan, err from nan  = 0xDB
err = 0xDB, nanl = nan, err from nanl = 0xDB
err from (double)nanl = 0x00
```

Comment: @pmg I think the question is here: "I am concerned with portability and wondering if there was a more standardized way to extract the error code from a nanl"

Comment: "IEEE 754 which, I am told, guarantees that integers and floating-points numbers have the same endianness on the same machine" <- I'm afraid not: IEEE 754 has precisely nothing to say about endianness. It deals only with bit strings. The word "endian" doesn't appear in the standard, and the word "byte" only appears once, in a sentence that implies that byte order is outside the scope of the standard.

Comment: @MarkDickinson, yes precisely, I am quite concerned about portability!
checking [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point) it says: "However, on modern standard computers (i.e., implementing IEEE 754), one may in practice safely assume that the endianness is the same for floating-point numbers as for integers", but no reference.  This is what I was referring to. If it is not true, then I need some idea on how to extract the error code...

Comment: close vote retracted @MarkDickinson, thanks

Comment: There is no standardized way to do this. The C standard does not specify IEEE-754 is used. It does not specify base two is used. It does not specify the order of bits within bytes or bytes within a `long double`. It does not specify the size of `long double` (beyond some lower bounds on its capabilities). It does not specify how the bits represent the floating-point value, except that they must form the sign, base-b numeral, exponent representation shown in C 2018 5.2.4.2.2 3. It does not specify the meaning of the argument to `nanl`.

Comment: If I had to do something like this, I would assume an IEEE-754 format of some width, documentation that and other assumptions, write code for widths we desired to support (e.g., 64-, 80-, and or 128-bit), use prepared values whose bit-string representations are known to probe that the bit-strings are stored in memory in an ordinary way, including detecting byte order, and exercise a few `nanl` calls to test how it is interpreting and storing the string. I.e., test as many of the unspecified things as reasonable.

Comment: User18192679, `*(uint64_t*)&d` --> Note that `double` size, alignment, endian-ness, etc. may differ from `uint64_t`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, I tested it on a little-endian directly and on a mock-up big-endian one and it works.  Your comment is stirring further my uneasiness with the `nanl` section of code... I will probably put a couple of #if in the code then ... Thanks

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica 64 bits for double is written in IEEE 754-1985.  I worked under the assumption that on the same machine the endianness of integers and floats is the same.  If the assumption had been wrong, users should have found `0x7F` as error code that does not correspond to anything and should have been reporting that (that portion of code, with minor modifications, has been around for almost 2 decades).  The problem here is not the `double` version of `nan`, but `nanl`, as extended precision can be 80 or 128 bits aligned in 12 or 16 bytes and there is no int96 or int128 to rely on.

Comment: @User18192679 Note that `double` may also be 64-bit.  C allows that and MS often does that.  Also 80 bit `long double` not have any padding (alignment 2).